# I am trying to use vuex in my project , but there is an error "[vuex] unknown action type"

Tags: vue.js, vuex

here is the code that I use vuex.

I search this error on google ,and some answer said this is because of the "namespaced:true",so I comment this line ,but the error still exist.

Also,If I directly use the test ,every thing is just fine.But when I put it in modules,It doesn't work.

```
//src/store/index.js

import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import test from './modules/test'

export default createStore({
  modules: {
    test
  }
})
```

```
//src/store/modules/test.js

import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  namespaced: true,
  state () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  },
  actions: {
    action_increment ({ commit }) {
      commit('increment')
    }
  }
})
```

the way I use it

```
methods: {
    test () {
      this.$store.dispatch('test/action_increment')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new store for your module. Look here https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html